What is the motivation behind small humans?
Browsing through the new 2024 Player's Handbook, I had huh? moment when reading the human species rules:

Size: Medium (about 4-7 feet tall) or Small (about 2-4 feet tall), chosen when you select this species.

Checking Wikipedia's confirmed list of the shortest people, I learned there are a total of maybe half a dozen people in recorded history that where 2 feet short, so it is not technically impossible to be human and 2 feet short. And pygmy peoples are defined as having an average male height of a little over 4 feet. Also, people with Dwarfism are defined to be smaller than a little over 4 feet. So this is a correct depiction of the range of variability that the human species has.
Still, in the past humans in the game were always medium sized (or the equivalent size range for that). For example, in 1e, height for a human male player character was 72 inches +/- 2-20 inches, so at the lower end with 52 inches well over 4 feet, never going down to 2 feet. If you wanted to play a small character, you’d play a halfling or gnome. Now that distinction is gone.
I know the game has made efforts to be more inclusive. Has there been any additional more specific designer commentary about why the size category was changed?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Willingness to Allow Greater Complexity
The only designer commentary on this matter that I can find occurs in this video released by Dungeons and Dragons (near 12:40) which discusses character creation in the 2024 rules. Jeremy Crawford says the following regarding species during character creation:

People will see that because we want each species to really bring its own fantasy to life, they're very assymetrical in how we have designed them. So some of them have choice points in them...you had mentioned the Goliath earlier where you might be picking a type of giant that you're associated with or Dragonborn have different breath weapon options. But then we have others like the Halfling, the Dwarf, the Orc where there aren't choice points like that because their fantasy didn't demand that in the design, but it's also because we did not want every single one to have the same complexity level. Just as our classes and subclasses have different complexity levels, the species have different complexity levels as well.

This quote immediately follows a discussion by Crawford regarding Humans having access to an additional Origin feat and starting off with Heroic Inspiration. In this regard, Humans can be complex race to play as because they have more choice points than other races might have. Among those choice points, size is one of them.
Players may choose to embrace this complexity if it helps them create the character they want. Or they may eschew it in favor of another race that has fewer choice points and lower complexity.

There is no mention of creature size as a choice for humans in that video, whether they may have implied that just by mentioning choice points is really up for debate.

@TreeSpawned you're correct, but the discussion suggests that Humans are a race with a lot of choices. You get to choose an Origin feat from a list of many, you get to choose a skill from a list of many. This information coupled with Crawford's discussion about races having varying degrees of complexity intentionally via choices is why I felt it was an appropriate inference regarding Humans having another choice to be Small or Medium. These videos don't necessarily cover every detail for the races, but they discuss the reasons why design choices were made. So the inference seemed appropriate.
